# Reading a file with Rust - borrowed value only lives until here

Tags: rust

I have a function that should read a file and returns it's contents.

```
fn read (file_name: &str) -> &str {

    let mut f = File::open(file_name)
        .expect(&format!("file not found: {}", file_name));

    let mut contents = String::new();

    f.read_to_string(&mut contents)
        .expect(&format!("cannot read file {}", file_name));

    return &contents;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
  --> src\main.rs:20:13
   |
20 |     return &contents;
   |             ^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
21 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
```

What am I doing wrong?

My Idea of what is happening here is this:

1. `let mut f = File::open(file_name).expect(....);` - this takes a handle of a file and tells the OS that we want to do things with it.
2. `let mut contents = String::new();` - this creates a vector-like data structure on the heap in order to store the data that we are about to read from the file.
3. `f.read_to_string(&mut contents).expect(...);` - this reads the file into the `contents` space.
4. `return &contents;` - this returns a pointer to the vector where the file data is stored.

Why am I not able to return the pointer that I want?

How do I close my file (the `f` variable)? I think that rust will close it for me after the variable goes out of scope, but what If I need to close it before that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the file handle being closed automatically when its variable goes out of scope; the same will happen to `contents`, though - it will be destroyed at the end of the function, unless you decide to return it as an owned `String`. In Rust functions can't return references to objects created inside them, only to those passed to them as arguments.

You can fix your function as follows:

```
fn read(file_name: &str) -> String {
    let mut f = File::open(file_name)
        .expect(&format!("file not found: {}", file_name));

    let mut contents = String::new();

    f.read_to_string(&mut contents)
        .expect(&format!("cannot read file {}", file_name));

    contents
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass `contents` as a mutable reference to the `read` function:

```
fn read(file_name: &str, contents: &mut String) { ... }
```

Comment: If you return the `String` from the function instead of a pointer does that mean that you are copying it in memory?

Comment: @HristoKolev: the specifics behind move semantics are [a separate topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490670/how-does-rust-provide-move-semantics) and potential LLVM optimizations are [a whole different story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571270/can-rust-optimise-away-the-bit-wise-copy-during-move-of-an-object-someday?rq=1) but, in general (outside of some `unsafe` magic perhaps), this is the way it is done in Rust.

Comment: But If I pass it as a `mut` parameter it doesn't do any copying?

Comment: @HristoKolev: in general it *shouldn't* - in most cases this is expected to be optimized away. You can always verify it with addresses like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571270/can-rust-optimise-away-the-bit-wise-copy-during-move-of-an-object-someday?rq=1) if you like.

Comment: Note that if you return the `String` from the function, it will probably copy the `String` **struct** (ie. a pointer and an int), but it won't copy the string **data** which is allocated on the heap and referenced by the pointer.