# Why does Rust not allow the copy and drop traits on one type?

Tags: rust, traits, move-semantics, ownership

From [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#stack-only-data-copy):

> Rust won’t let us annotate a type with the `Copy` trait if the type, or any of its parts, has implemented the `Drop` trait. If the type needs something special to happen when the value goes out of scope and we add the `Copy` annotation to that type, we’ll get a compile time error.

Why was the design decision made to disallow `Copy` and `Drop` on the same type?

Comment: This is kinda-sorta a formalization of what C++ calls the ["Rule of Three"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

- The `Drop` trait is used in an [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) context, typically when some resource needs to be released/closed when the object is destroyed.
- In the other hand, a `Copy` type is a trivial type that can be copied with a `memcpy` only.

With those two descriptions, it is clearer that they are exclusive: it makes no sense to `memcpy` nontrivial data: what if we copy the data, and we drop one of the copies? The inner resource of the other copy will not be reliable anymore.

In fact, `Copy` in not even a "real" trait, in that it does not define any function. It is a special **marker** that says to the compiler: "you can duplicate myself with a simple bytes copy". So you cannot provide a custom implementation of `Copy`, because there is no implementation at all. However, you can mark a type as copyable:

```
impl Copy for Foo {}
```

or better, with a derive:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Foo { /* ... */ }
```

This builds only if all the fields implement `Copy`. Otherwise, the compiler refuses to compile because this is unsafe.

---

For the sake of an example, let's suppose that the `File` struct implements `Copy`. Of course, this is **not** the case, and this example is wrong and cannot compile:

```
fn drop_copy_type<T>(T x)
where
    T: Copy + Drop,
{
    // The inner file descriptor is closed there:
    std::mem::drop(x);
}

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("foo.txt").unwrap();
    drop_copy_type(file);
    let mut contents = String::new();

    // Oops, this is unsafe!
    // We try to read an already closed file descriptor:
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: "With those two descriptions, it is clearer that they are exclusive" what about an implementation of a shared pointer?

Comment: @sdgfsdh When you copy a shared pointer, you have to increment the inner reference counter. That's not a simple `memcpy`. See the [drop implementation of `Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#830) for example.

Comment: So Rust does not allow custom implementations of `Copy`?

Comment: @sdgfsdh Nope. Let me add more information about this in my answer.

Comment: @sdgfsdh actually rust allows something like a custom implementation of `Copy`. It is called `Clone`. `Clone` is always explizit, can perform additional operations (such as increasing a reference count), and can coexist with `Drop`.

Comment: Is `Copy` trait about byte copying from the stack only and not from, for example, the heap? In other words, is this trait a tool for saying the compilier "you can copy bytes from stack for another variable, that's sufficient to do" and if some type presupposes a heap resource, then `Copy` has to avoided (cause the compilier don't trail heap resources)?

Comment: Every `Copy` is also `Clone`, and they both don't care about the data emplacement. If you want to know if the copies are optimized away, I think that this answer is still relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571270/can-rust-optimise-away-the-bit-wise-copy-during-move-of-an-object-someday @Mergasov

Comment: @Mergasov the `Copy` trait doesn't know anything about stack vs heap. For example, if I have some `&i32`, that might point to something on either one. (Or neither. It could also point to a static value in the "data segment", or anything else that's addressable in memory.) Regardless, the fact that `i32` is `Copy` means I can dereference that pointer and copy the value behind it.

Answer (score 15):

The other answers here are talking about why we don't usually *want* to implement both `Copy` and `Drop` for the same type, but that's not the same as explaining why it's *forbidden*. It might seem like a toy example like this should work just fine:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Foo {
    i: i32,
}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // No problematic memory management here. Just print.
        println!("{}", self.i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo1 = Foo { i: 42 };
    let foo2 = foo1;
    // Shouldn't this just print 42 twice?
}
```

But indeed, if we try to compile that (using Rust 1.52), it fails as expected:

```
error[E0184]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type; the type has a destructor
 --> src/main.rs:1:10
  |
1 | #[derive(Copy, Clone)]
  |          ^^^^ Copy not allowed on types with destructors
  |
  = note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0184`.
```

See the "For more information" note at the bottom? Those are often helpful. Let's run `rustc --explain E0184`:

````
The `Copy` trait was implemented on a type with a `Drop` implementation.

Erroneous code example:

```
#[derive(Copy)]
struct Foo; // error!

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
    }
}
```

Explicitly implementing both `Drop` and `Copy` trait on a type is currently
disallowed. This feature can make some sense in theory, but the current
implementation is incorrect and can lead to memory unsafety (see
[issue #20126][iss20126]), so it has been disabled for now.

[iss20126]: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20126
````

Following that issue link leads to a discussion of "zeroing-on-drop". Present-day Rust doesn't do this anymore, but [up until around 2016 Rust implemented "dynamic drop" by zeroing all the bits of a value when dropping it](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0320-nonzeroing-dynamic-drop.html#how-dynamic-drop-semantics-works). But of course that isn't a valid implementation if a type can be both `Copy` and `Drop` -- Rust can't zero out a value that you're allowed to keep using -- so implementing both of those traits on the same type was disallowed. The discussion ends with [this interesting comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20126#issuecomment-68603652):

> Anyhow, it's easiest to forbid it for now. We can always make it legal later if someone comes up with a persuasive use case. Idempotent destructors seem like a bit of an odd thing.

---

What's above is the explanation for Rust's current behavior, as best I can tell. But I think there's another reason to keep things the way they are, which I haven't seen discussed: `Copy` currently implies that a value can be both bitwise copied *and also bitwise overwritten*. Consider this code:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Foo {
    i: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut ten_foos = [Foo { i: 42 }; 10];
    let ten_more_foos = [Foo { i: 99 }; 10];
    // Overwrite all the bytes of the first array with those of the second.
    unsafe {
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(&ten_more_foos, &mut ten_foos, 1);
    }
}
```

This unsafe code is totally fine today. In fact, `[T]::copy_from_slice` will do exactly the same thing for any `T: Copy`. But would it still be ok, if `Foo` (or any other `Copy` type) were allowed to be `Drop`? Our code here, and the standard library code in `copy_from_slice`, would be destroying objects without dropping them!

Now, *technically*, failing to call the destructor of an object is allowed. There was a [very interesting discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24292) back in the day that led to `std::mem::forget` going from `unsafe` to safe shortly before Rust 1.0. So it's possible that Rust could allow `Copy` + `Drop` without leading to any undefined behavior, despite this issue. But it would be quite surprising that certain (standard!) functions would fail to call the destructors you expect. The property that "`Copy` objects can be bitwise copied *and bitwise overwritten*" seems like a good one to keep.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/marker/trait.Copy.html#when-cant-my-type-be-copy).

> [...] [A]ny type implementing [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) can't be `Copy`, because it's managing some resource besides its own [`size_of::<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) bytes.