# Is it available to drop a variable holding a primitive value in Rust?

Tags: rust

**Updated Question:**

Or I can ask this way: for every type `T`, if it's `Copy`, then there is no way for it to be moved, right? I mean is there any way like the `std::move` in C++ can move a copyable value explicitly?

---

**Original Question:**

Presume we have below a piece of Rust code, in this code, I defined a variable `x` holding an i32 value. What I want to do is to drop its value and invalidate it. I tried to use `ptr::drop_in_place` to drop it through a pointer, but it doesn't work, why?

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 10;
    use std::ptr;
    unsafe {
        ptr::drop_in_place(&mut x as *mut i32);
    }
    println!("{}", x);  // x is still accessible here.
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're doing is safe or not, but I'm not sure what you want to achieve either. An `i32` doesn't have any [drop behavior](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b6e56e5132bd1801ec7b80b4f71b50a).

Comment: So, seems for every type T, if it's `Copy`, then there is no way for it to be moved, right?

Answer (score 3):

> For every type `T`, if it's `Copy`, then there is no way for it to be moved, right?

That is one way to word it. The semantics of [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) are such that any *move* leaves the original object valid.

Because of this, and that [`Drop` and `Copy` are mutually exclusive traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704063/why-does-rust-not-allow-the-copy-and-drop-traits-on-one-type), there's no way to "drop" a `Copy`. The traditional method of calling `std::mem::drop(x)` won't work. The only meaningful thing you can do is let the variable fall out of scope:

```
fn main() {
    {
        let x = 10;
    }
    println!("{}", x);  // x is no longer accessible here.
}
```

> I mean is there any way like the `std::move` in C++ can move a copyable value explicitly?

The specifics of copying vs moving are quite different between C++ and Rust. *All* types are moveable in Rust, whereas its opt-in for C++. And moving and copying in Rust are always bitwise copies, there's no room for custom code. Moving in Rust leaves the source object invalid whereas its still useable as a value in C++.

I can go on, but I'll leave off one last bit: *moving* a primitive in C++ isn't different than a copy either.